# Pausing a song in iTunes using the space bar no longer works after upgrade to Lion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, itunes, osx-lion

I used to be able to switch to iTunes using cmd-tab and press the space bar to pause a song as it was playing.  This allowed me to to stop the song quickly when I was interrupted by a phone call.

However, this no longer works.  I can only go to the Controls menu item in iTunes and select Controls --> Pause.

I do see that the menu item "Pause" is mapped to "space".  When I press the space bar now with iTunes as the "active" application I just hear a tone.  Recently I upgraded both Lion and iTunes so I am not quite sure which one stopped this from working properly.

Does anyone know how to get this functionality back?

Comment: I think this is a bug.

Comment: I have iTunes 10.4.1, no relevant custom shortcuts and the same issue when the iTunes main window isn't open. How did you solve your issue?

Comment: @DanielBeck I edited my answer with an alternate solution that should work for you until this problem is fixed by Apple.

Comment: @SnapShot Actually, that solution is how I learned do it anyway (while also getting used to pressing F8 ;) ). Thanks for staying on this topic!

Comment: To follow up on this question - this is now fixed in iTunes 10.5

Comment: Yes indeed, this sucks, especially for listen to lectures and taking notes at the same time. But I think it's too painful to wait for it to be fixed. I am training myself to use the marked audio control keys (F6-F8). These have the benefit of pausing/playing iTunes while having other applications in the foreground. But it's stupid to direct space into the search field, space is a perfect emergency pause button for audio/video. F8 is too awkward to quickly pause when you might be scrambling to answer the phone/door, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't common for most people that upgrade to Lion. All 5 macs I have checked didn't have the application shortcuts change and space still maps correctly to play/pause in iTunes.

[image]

Have you tried making a new user account or resetting your keyboard shortcuts to the defaults (and cleaning out any un-needed Application shortcuts after the upgrade? There have been several threads on where all sorts of system keyboard shortcuts didn't survive an upgrade. I don't know if this is some bug in the upgrade scripts or just that some damage that was harmless in the preference list files is now a problem in Lion.

Also, from reading the comments - make sure iTunes is the frontmost app with a proper window showing. If you need to pause the music when other apps are present - you might look into a special widget like [Take Five](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/take-five/id424437399?mt=12).

Comment: Thanks for much for your help. Those are great suggestions.

Comment: This only occurs if there's no iTunes main window open. Clicking the menu item still works, but not pressing space.

Comment: bmike, I appreciate your response, but if the menu item is visible, enabled, and has a keyboard shortcut *independent* from main window state, I expect its keyboard shortcut to *work* independent from main window state. Just like any other window/document independent menu item shortcut in any other application. It'd be different if the menu item were deactivated while the main window were closed, *but it isn't*. Clicking works when the iTunes main window is closed, pressing `space` doesn't.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all that there aren't even two issues at play. It's fairly clear to me that it's not just an iTunes bug - I've gone to no less than 12 macs at various 10.7 / 10.7.1 and 10.4 / 10.4.1 and _none_ of them are having this. I'm sure you have an issue - just not able to dissect it since things work in general for me. I hope someone has better ideas for your situation. I don't know if it's better at this point to ask another question referring to this and stating that the selected answer _does not_ work for you and solicit additional ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed after I upgraded to iTunes 10.4.1  The update notes for 10.4.1 mentioned fixing a problem with media keys on third party keyboards.  This was not exactly my problem because I saw this issue both on a Logitech keyboard and on the built in Macbook laptop keyboard.  However, immediately after upgrading iTunes the space bar started working properly so perhaps there was a problem during the Lion upgrade that was fixed by the iTunes 10.4.1 update.

If upgrading does not work for you I can offer the following alternative.

First, this is only a problem if the if the main iTunes window is closed or minimized.  You can follow the following steps to stop and start the music without using the mouse:

1. cmd-tab to iTunes so it is the foreground application
2. Press cmd-opt-1. This will bring up main iTunes window to the foreground
3. Press the space bar to stop or start the music
4. Press cmd-m to minimize the main iTunes window again

This involves one or two extra steps but it works well enough until this problem is fixed.

Comment: Awesome - sometimes it's nice for things to get fixed on their own rather than needing to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and it seems to have started after 'upgrading' to iTunes 10.5

At first i thought the spacebar no longer controlled play/pause but now what I see is happening is that iTunes is defaulting to the search field so when I switch to iTunes and hit the spacebar, iTunes searches for a 'space'... duh. Once I've clicked my library however, the spacebar resumes its playback control but that completely defeats the purpose of course. Lame.